# Проверка пароля на совпадение подряд идущих символов

Tags: java

Мне необходимо проверить есть ли в пароле, вводимом пользователем повторение ПОДРЯД идущих символов в количестве, введенном в переменную maxRepeats. То есть если maxRepeats 2, то пароль может иметь вид pasword, password, passsword и не более. Чет я тут встрял. Необходимо решить одинарным циклом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! 1. [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119) 2. [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: а чего это если 2, то можно passsword, в котором 3?

Comment: Индексы символов в непустой строке в диапазоне `[0, str.length() - 1]`.  И уточните, почему при `maxRepeats = 2` разрешается 3 символа.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант решения с циклом, с алгоритмом фактически описанным в ответе @DmitryK:

```java
public boolean verify(String password) {
    int n = password.length();
    if (n < minLength) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 1, count = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (password.charAt(i) == password.charAt(i - 1)) {
            if (++count > maxRepeats) { // количество повторов превысило лимит
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            count = 1; // сброс счётчика символов
            if (maxRepeats >= n - i) {
                break; // отбросить проверку конца строки
            }
        }
    }
    return true; // длина не превышена
}
```

---

Также для решения подобного рода задач можно использовать регулярные выражения и метод `String::matches`:

```java
public boolean verify(String password) {
    if (password.length() < minLength) {
        return false;
    }
    return !password.matches(".*(.)\\1{" + maxRepeats + ",}.*");
}
```

`".*(.)\\1{" + maxRepeats + ",}.*"`:

- `.*` пропустить символы в начале и конце и строки
- `(.)\\1{" + maxRepeats + ",}` - найти любой символ `(.)`, после которого идёт аналогичный со ссылкой на обнаруженный ранее `\\1`, в количестве *как минимум* `maxRepeats`

Или же более производительный вариант c использованием `Matcher::find`:

```java
public boolean verify(String password) {
    return !Pattern.compile("(.)\\1{" + maxRepeats + ",}").matcher(password).find();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проходите по строке начиная со 2 символа и поддерживаете счетчик повторений.
На каждой итерации сравниваете символ с предыдущим.
Если символ не совпадает - обнуляете счетчик.
Если совпадает - увеличиваете счетчик повторений и сравниваете с `maxRepeats`.
Если счетчик повторений стал больше разрешенного - значит условие нарушено (повторений символа больше).
Получается подсчет повторений за 1 проход.